# ContentTypeService failed to find a content type with alias "homePage"

Tags: umbraco7

***Error:
ContentTypeService failed to find a content type with alias "homePage"
This usually indicates that the content cache is corrupt; the content cache has been rebuilt in an attempt to self-fix the issue.***

I've only just started tinkering with this CMS after watching a few videos, but it looks like the site has got screwed up.

I've deleted ALL pages, templates, doc types and started again, but the homePage content type doesn't even exist anymore so not sure why it is even erroring on this and also no idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is it the umbraco backend that is throwing the error?

Comment: Yes its the yellow screen of death error (.NET).  I think I fixed it by restarting IIS. I don't think Umbraco likes you doing major changes at root nodes/re-assigning templates to content pages. However, this is on a more or less empty site, so a bit surprised at such a fatal error early on.